# Converting the return value of json_decode to booleam

Tags: php, json, boolean, return-value

i am using a web service in my php code which returns its return value in form of json, for example: `{"d":false} or {"d":true};`

I googled a lot for two days but there is nothing to get just the boolean value; I mean I need a way which just change this result to the false or true in the normal form we always use in our programming.

I found a lot of answers on net which work well for converting the string value. for example if the service was returning the value in form of {"d":"value"} they work fine and I can get the "value" using these answers. but my problem is the return value is boolean in json.

any help will be appreciated!

Regards!

Comment: Do you have any example code you can show possibly the part you are doing the decode in?

Comment: its perfectly fine, just use it normally